# Flutter - how to supply init value of TextField with dynamic value from FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter

I'm making an 'edit user profile' page where I want to download data from `FutureBuilder` into `TextField`, to allow users to modify it. I know that `TextEditingController()` has a property called text, but I don't know how to dynamically pass the global variable called `createdUser` to it.

FutureBuilder:

```
FutureBuilder<Prefix.User>(
      future: createUser(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        var user;
          (...)
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          final userName = snapshot.data.username;

          user = Prefix.User(username: userName);

          widget.createdUser = user;
        }
```

And I want do do something like that in TextEditingController :

```
  TextEditingController messageTextController = TextEditingController(
      text: createdUser.username);
```

I've tried to pass data through constructor, but without effect, I know there's need to be some simple solution. FutureBuilder works ok, because when I've tried to use it to display as hint value it was ok.

Comment: You just missed to add setState inside the if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare your controller like this:-

```
TextEditingController messageTextController = TextEditingController();
```

and in your future builder

```
    FutureBuilder<Prefix.User>(
          future: createUser(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            var user;
              (...)
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              final userName = snapshot.data.username;
    
              user = Prefix.User(username: userName);
    
              widget.createdUser = user;
              messageTextController.text=createdUser.username;//this will add the value of username to the controller
            }
```